# WPF ShowDialog always crash point?

Tags: wpf, debugging, visual-studio-2015

I have a main window which has some menu buttons leading off onto other WPF windows.
I'm having a problem with the code behind the WPF when it crashes.
VS debugger is always showing the crash coming from my 'form.ShowDialog()' instead of the code thats actually creating the crash.
See image.
From the output I can tell its me trying to read one of my SQL database entries which is null.
My question, why does the debugger show this position form.ShowDialog() and not the actual code that broke eg

```
j.Status = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Status"]);
```

[image]

Comment: Are you doing something on constructor of Form? exception is much clear that there is a cast error either on constructor or any control event

Comment: I'm passing a stackpanel pointer through the constructor, but there is no further logical beyond the component initialise.
I have a bunch of button created in the UpdateListBox function.
The form crashes when one of the buttons is pressed which calls a database request.

Comment: Then the problem can be in the `UpdateListbox`. The `Initializecomponents()' must raise an error, and unfortunately it's rarely clear.... Please share more code.

Answer (score 0):

You can pinpoint easier why the dialog fails by looking at the initialization. In the dialog you are trying to display with **ShowDialog()**, change the code behind constructor and add a try catch. The dialog encounters an exception and cannot succesfully complete **InitializeComponent()** e.g:

```
try {
 InitializeComponent();
}
catch (Exception err) {
 Debug.Writeline(err);
}
```

Inspect why the dialog cannot initialize with a breakpoint in the catch clause.